# What database to use with Cocoa (OS X) in Xcode 6 (language : Swift)

Tags: database, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I am a Software Developer in .net and new to Xcode.
I am creating an application for **MAC OS X** using **Cocoa framework** in **Xcode 6** using **Swift**. 
I would like to know what kind of database to use with it.
I have searched all over the internet but i could only find proper tutorials for iOS only or for previous version of Xcode or for C++ coming across **Core Data** and **FMDB** etc and hit a dead end in every tutorial.

My database will have many inter-related tables with many validations and I would be using CRUD functionality.

So please tell me which kind (or which) database to use, how to use it and give me some links for tutorials if possible.

Comment: What do you use with `.Net`?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa way would be with CoreData. Strictly speaking this is not a database but a way to structure your model layer using relationships.

If you want a more traditional database then I'd just use SQL wrapper. For example, https://github.com/marcoarment/FCModel